# How to check if a popup is open in Tridion JS Framework (Anguilla)?

Tags: cme

So I do like this when user click a button:

```
var popup = $popup.create(url, features, options);
popup.open();
```

The problem is that every time the user clicks, a new popup is opened. I tried popup.isOpen() but is always false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isOpen()` is the correct method to call. It will return `true` any time in between the `open()` method being called and the `close()` method being called.

Maybe you are creating a new popup every time and that's why it is always `false`? You should keep the variable around (usually in this.properties) and check for `null` and `isOpen()` before you create a new popup.

Something like this:

```js
var c = this.properties.controls;
if (c.popup && c.popup.isOpen())
{
   // Already open - do something (e.g. send new parameters to it)
   return;
} 

c.popup = $popup.create(url, features, options);
c.popup.open();
```

Comment: Only to add that the possible action to do when the popup is already open is c.popup.focus(); to bring it to the front view